# How to to cancel pending API when going to next page in reactjs using Axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-typescript

How to to cancel pending API when going to next page in reactjs using Axios?

I am calling more than 5 API in a single page, When I navigate to that page, (/userProfile) calling API one by one, till all called and get the response, so all API are queue. but when I immediately leave that page to another page (/myTrans), all API of  /userProfile  is pending, after success then API of this  /myTrans is calling, How do I should cancel or abort all pending API of /userProfile.

```
my axios.ts


import Snackbar from "awesome-snackbar";
import _axios from "axios";
import LocalStorageKey from "../constants/LocalStorageKey";
const baseURL =
  process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL;

const axios = _axios.create({ baseURL });

axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  var X_AUTH_TOKEN =
    localStorage.getItem(LocalStorageKey.token);
  const X_VERIFY_TOKEN = localStorage.getItem("vkey") ?? "";

  if (X_AUTH_TOKEN === 'undefined') {
    X_AUTH_TOKEN = "eyJhbGciI1NiIsInR5c"
  }

  if (X_AUTH_TOKEN !== '') {
    config.headers.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${X_AUTH_TOKEN}`);
  }
  config.headers.set("X-Verify-Key", X_VERIFY_TOKEN);

  return config;
},

  error => {
    return Promise.reject(error)
  }

);

axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
    const { response } = error;
    if (response) {
      const errorObject = response.data;
      const code = errorObject.result_code;

      if (code === 401) {
        new Snackbar("Your login session has expired. Please login again")
      }

      throw errorObject;
    }

    throw error;
  }
);

export default axios;
```

my profile.ts

```
import axios from "../axios";



export const getClientProfile = async () => {
    const res = await axios
        .get("/client/profile")
        .then((respons) => {
            console.log(" Client Profile respons ", respons.data);
            return respons.data as ClientProfileModel;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            return null;
        });

    return res;
};
export const getAddtionalInfo = async (target?: any) => {

    const res = await axios
        .get(`/client/personalDetail?target=${target}`)
        .then((respons) => {
            console.log("/client/personalDetail", respons);
            return respons.data
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            return null;
        });

    return res;
};
```

UserProfile.tsx

```
  useEffect(() => {
 getClientProfile().then((res) => {
        setClientProfile(res);
      
      });
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AbortController for this, and it should be something like this:

```js
const controller = new AbortController();

const response = await axios.get(
  `/whateverAPI`, {
    controller.signal
  }
);
```

and use:

```js
controller.abort();
```

When you want to cancel.